# Extracting out numbers in a list from R

Tags: r

I am reading this from a CSV file, and i need to write a function that churns out a final data frame, so given a particular entry, i have

> x
>   [1] {2,4,5,11,12}

139 Levels:  {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,12,17} ...

i can change it to 
x2<-as.character(x)

which gives me

> x
>   [1] "{2,4,5,11,12}"

how do i extract 2,4,5,11,12 out? (having 5 elements)

i have tried to use various ways, like gsub, but to no avail

can anyone please help me?

Comment: Are you wanting a dataframe x with n columns where pos1 value from a row appears in col1, pos2 value in col2 and so on, or are you after a dataframe with x$obsnumber and x$obsvalue such that the n values have a row each?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're trying to import a database table that contains arrays. Since R doesn't know about such data structures, it treats them as text.

Try this. I assume the column in question is `x`. The result will be a list, with each element being the vector of array values for that row in the table.

```
dat <- read.csv("<file>", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dat$x <- strsplit(gsub("\\{(.*)\\}", "\\1", dat$x), ",")
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply,

i realized there is no need to do read it stringasfactor=FALSE,

ahkao<-data$Q9a1[37]
ahkao2<-as.character(ahkao)
ahkao5<-strsplit(gsub("\\{(.*)\\}", "\\1", ahkao2), ",")

and it returns me 

[1] "2"  "4"  "5"  "11" "12"

but this is still length 1, how do i seperate this into 5 different elements? i cannot seem to convert it to numeric either.